Who chooses the order of damage replacement effects?
If I deal damage to a permanent or player with a +2 damage replacement effect from Torbran, Thane of Redfell or Rankle and Torbran, and an X2 damage replacement effect from Twinflame Tyrant or Obosh, the Preypiercer, do I, the controller of the damage source, get to decide to do the +2 then the X2 or does my opponent, owner of the permanent/the player I'm doing damage to, get to chose the order saying X2 then +2?

Board & Card Games facilitates questions about many games. What game are you asking about? Is this a question about Magic: the Gathering?

@doppelgreener 4 magic the gatheric cards were called out by name, easy to fix the issue.

Your opponent gets to choose the order these replacement effects apply. This is covered by rule 616.1 of the Comprehensive Rules (emphasis mine):

616.1 If two or more replacement and/or prevention effects are attempting to modify the way an event affects an object or player, the affected object’s controller (or its owner if it has no controller) or the affected player chooses one to apply, following the steps listed below. If two or more players have to make these choices at the same time, choices are made in APNAP order (see rule 101.4).

Because the your opponent or their creature is the one being affected by the damage being replaced, they get to choose the order these replacement effects apply to that damage. This is further made clear on the rulings for Torbran, Thane of Redfell (emphasis mine):

If another effect modifies how much damage your red source would deal, including preventing some of it, the player being dealt damage or the controller of the permanent being dealt damage chooses an order in which to apply those effects. If all of the damage is prevented, Torbran’s effect no longer applies.

